# Comma in a Lambda Calculus as an operator?

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

I'm learning Lambda Calculus (self taught). I've got a fairly basic understanding of the operators (or lack thereof) and how they work. In my book, I recently came across 
λx, y . x + y

This is the first time I've seen a comma, and my book does not cover commas in Lambda Calculus. I'm wondering if this is a typo or if I'm missing something. I've searched google but I've come up empty handed.

Comment: Without context, I can't be sure, but I'd think that that's a way to express `λx . (λy . x + y)`.

Comment: It's basically just using it as an example problem at the end of the chapter, asking to reduce it. Not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: you might want to reconsider the book because there's no such thing as `,` or  `x + y` in lambda calc

Comment: I can't comment for a lack of rep. In the book it also says "Assume an Applied calculus, where the operators ( + - * / ) are legal well-formed terms in the language, and parentheses are allowed."